# Velocity Template engine - key-value-map

Tags: apache, templates, transformation, velocity

I have some problems wo use a key-value-map into Velocity.

Someone has an example of this functionality?

```
$myMap ={}

$myMap.put("mykey1", "myvalue")
$myMap.delete("mykey1")
$myMap.getValue("mykey1")
```

Answer (score 22):

As Nathan said, you should use:

```
#set ($myMap = {})
```

to create a new map and assign it to a variable.

Now, why is the `put` call printed.

1. Anything that is not inside a directive, like `#set(not printed)` or `#if(not printed)` or `#foreach(again not printed)`, is printed, including free text, variables, and **method calls**.
2. Velocity can't distinguish between the different semantics of `$myMap.get('mykey')` and `$myMap.put('key', 'value')` (reader vs. writer), so the result of the `put` call is printed, just like any other method.
3. Whenever something can't be properly evaluated, because a variable is not defined or somewhere along the line a method returns `null`, the code that failed to be evaluated is dumped literally into the output.
4. As the documentation of the `put` method states, the function returns the previous value stored for that key, or `null` if no value was set at all.
5. Summing it all up, it's normal to get that line printed.

To try this theory out, you can do this:

```
#set ($myMap = {})
$myMap.put('key', 'first value')
$myMap.put('key', 'second value')
$myMap.get('key')
```

This will be printed:

```
$myMap.put('key', 'first value')
first value
second value
```

There are two things you can do so that the line isn't printed:

1. Store the outcome of the function in a temporary variable: `#set ($discard = $myMap.put('key', 'value')`
2. Use the silent method call: `$!myMap.put('key', 'value')`

I'd recommend the first one, since the second one will still print something when you're replacing an existing value.

Comment: 3. `#if ($myMap.put('key', 'value'))#end`

Answer (score 3):

Did you try doing:

```
#set( $myMap = {} )
```

Also, make sure you are using a modern version of Velocity. Ancient ones did not have map syntax in VTL.

Comment: Oh, I've probably made ​​a mistake all the time. #set( $myMap = {} ) + $myMap.put("mykey1", "myvalue") creates the output > $myMap.put("mykey1", "myvalue"). I just started with Velocity. I thought when the command is part of the output, the command was not accepted/recognized. Is it a bug or why the command is part ot the output if everything is running correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Just add ! to not print put:
$!myMap.put('key', 'second value')